# Can Templates in Chef be applied in an order?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Lets say I have a common template where the recipe looks like this:

```rb
template '/tmp/message' do
  source 'message.erb'
  variables(
    :version => 'common version',
    :features => 'common features'
    )
end
```

and the `message.erb` looked like this:

```
The version is <%= @version %>
The features are  <%= @features %>
```

**Now** lets say after applying that I want to then override 'features' with another message but leave the 'version' the same so that it looks like this:

```
The version is common version
The features are really cool features
```

Can this be done?

I am hoping I can apply a 'cool features' recipe that looks something like this:

```rb
template '/tmp/message' do
  source 'message.erb'
  variables(
    :features => 'really cool features'
    )
end
```

where it only overrides the values I want to override and leaves the previously changed values in place.

Answer (score 1):

Use [attributes](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_attributes.html) instead of multiple templates to define such values. The attributes can be set from different places and afterwards, create the `template` that fills in the contents of these attributes.

Comment: thanks - ended up doing something like this : https://github.com/tinytelly/chef-simple-overrides